# how to create this query

Tags: sql, mysql, aggregate-functions

how to create a query if i need to include two aggregate function in select row and per each  function i need different group by and where conditions 
in my example i need to returns the playerName, and how many the player win the this can be checked if the results in table game result= first, and how many times he played

but do not know how to deal with two aggregate functions .

simply i want to join the result of this two queries

1.

```
select playeName,count(*)
from  player,game
where player.playerId=game.playerId and result="first"
group by game.playerId
```

2.

```
select count(*)
from game, player
where game.playerId=player.playerId
group by game.playerId
```

the set of attributes for table game are 
playerId , result
the set of attributes for table player are 
playerName,playerId

any idea???

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
  SELECT p.playername,
         SUM(CASE WHEN g.result = 'first' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
         COUNT(*)
    FROM PLAYER p
    JOIN GAME g ON g.playerid = p.playerid
GROUP BY p.playername
```

Comment: it works thanx but could you please explain each step as much as you can :) please Mr.OMG

Comment: but waite some this wrong when i see the record it returns that some of the player wins 0 !!! impossible

Comment: @Lenord: Yes, if a player doesn't have any games where result equals "first" -- the value will be zero.  The column always has to be present in the output if you want to show it -- what were you expecting to see?

Answer (score 0):

Along with solutions proposed by **OMG Ponies** and **Bnjmn**, you can also get desired results by using `WITH ROLLUP`

```
select result, count(*)
from game, player
where game.playerId=player.playerId
group by game.playerId, result WITH ROLLUP
```

Then, on client side, find records with result equals 'first' and and result is null(which is #games played).