# Sort 0-valued database rows after non-zero rows

Tags: mysql, sorting

```
id rank 
5   1
3   2
4   3

1   0
2   0
6   0
```

This results : `rank = 0`  after `rank > 0`

I don't kwow how to use `SQL ORDER BY` sorting results

Comment: SELECT * FROM table WHERE fieldname=value ORDER BY rank ASC. Use ORDER BY .. ASC or DESC. That's the simplest way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
  SELECT *
    FROM mytable
ORDER BY IF(rank > 0, 0, 42),
         rank
```

Where `42` is **any positive** number. I've choosen 42 just because it is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Answer_to_the_Ultimate_Question_of_Life,_the_Universe,_and_Everything

Comment: @Phrogz: yup ;-) Just mentioned that 42 is the most appropriate here ;-)

Comment: @zerkms Is that some sort of bizarre haiku formatting you're going for?

Comment: @Phrogz: I like to name it "pony-style", just because it was invented by http://stackoverflow.com/users/135152/omg-ponies. You can look at how he formats the queries. I think (as well as many users here do) it is handy.

Comment: @zerkms I don't think he ever indents the leading `SELECT` farther than subordinate pieces. (Also, I'm pretty sure he didn't invent multi-line SQL formatting.) *shrug*

Comment: @Phrogz: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4473401/how-to-create-this-query/4473456#4473456

Comment: @zerkms I stand corrected! I browsed a few of his other answers and did not see it.

Comment: @Phrogz: may be he did not do that, but I never seen in books or any other people who format sql in the same way.