# MySQL Order by 2 columns with if statement

Tags: mysql, if-statement

I have a problem with ordering a search result by 2 colums.

I have a table in following format

```
id  pos date
------------------
65  0   2012-08-10
66  0   2012-08-09
70  0   2012-08-08
73  0   2012-08-07
74  0   2012-08-06
75  0   2012-08-05
76  1   2012-08-04
77  2   2012-08-03
78  0   2012-08-02
79  0   2012-08-01
```

My problem is, that the system (cms) produces (int)0's for *NULL* . SO i get not the result, i need.

I want to order by pos(if not (int)0 and than date), so that pos only forces the position, when it is **>=1** 
My question. Is there a way to use an IF statement in the ORDER clause?

Comment: So what is the desired result order for your example data? You want the `pos=0` ones to come last?

Comment: How should pos=0 be sorted? not at all? Interleaved with other rows? at the end? left out from the result set?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4581856/sort-0-valued-database-rows-after-non-zero-rows

Comment: pos should be ignored, when it is (int)0.

Comment: What does ignoring it mean? Where do these go relative to rows where `pos` is specified? Please show us the desired results for your example data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To sort according to `pos` if and only if it's set, and leave all zeroes for last ordered by date; the **4E9** is just a number high enough to be larger than all the values in `pos`.

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable 
ORDER BY CASE pos WHEN 0 THEN 4E9 ELSE pos END, `date`;
```

Demo [at SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7bc73/3).

Another a bit simpler mysql-specific version that gets rid of the "magic constant" is this;

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable 
ORDER BY pos=0, pos, `date`;
```

Another [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7bc73/5).